# contents() in <object type="text/html"></object>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object-tag

I can access local contents loaded in an `<iframe>` with

`$("#frame").contents().find('div').css(...)`

When using a `<object type="text/html">` instead (same local site), the contents function does not work.

Is there another way or did I miss something ?

Here follows the test code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2-min.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/try.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="here_goes_a_proprietary_side_i_dont_want_to_mess_inside">
        <object id="frame" type="text/html" data="/nastysite/index.php" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    alert("go ?");  //temporary solution to wait until everything is loaded.
    $("#frame").contents().find('div').css("background-color", "red"); //nothing appens
    console.debug($("#frame").contents().find('div'));  //nothing
});
```

Comment: Is the iframe loading from a different domain ? I believe JavaScript doesn't allow that. Try your code with an iframe that loads something locally.

Comment: It is a local content.

Comment: If you are already using jquery why dont you just use `$(targetElement).load('/nastysite/index.php');`? It would seem a lot less complex than using the object method.

Comment: It was my first idea, however this site contains an old version of jquery with a lot of plugins. Off course i tried noConflict() and noConflict(true), without great success.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same question.

Answer (score -1):

Your object tag closes immediately, so it has no child div to find.

```
<object id="frame" type="text/html" data="/nastysite/index.php" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
```

Comment: While its true he needs to use a full closing tag and not short syntax, im still not sure if it will expose the DOM of the page he is "importing".

Comment: Tried with the short syntax, but it has no more effect (the site is still loaded successfully).