# Access external HTML page content of object tags

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I've searched an answer to this question but can't get a way how to do it.

I want to access the content of a div that I have included in an object tag.

My include.htm file:

```
<div id="includedDiv">This is the included page</div>
```

What I have tried :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Get element from object included page</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Test: This is the main page</p>
<object id="obj" data="include.htm"></object>
<script>
//alert(document.getElementById("includedDiv").firstChild.nodeValue);
//alert((document.getElementById("obj")).document.getElementById("includedDiv").firstChild.nodeValue);
alert(document.getElementById("obj")["includedDiv"]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

None of the alert prints me the message "This is the included page", is there a way to get this content from the DOM?

EDIT:
window[0].document.getElementById("includedDiv").firstChild.nodeValue; was the the good answer for access through the DOM, object tag just creates another window :)
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_length.asp

Comment: Possible clue, the content I want to access is on an external page, some people say object tag closes immediately, so there is no child to find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981191/jquery-contents-in-object-type-text-html-object
It seems possible to load content of an external HTML page with jQuery load method or using the native Javascript AJAX method XMLHttpRequest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728520/get-innerhtml-from-external-page-with-javascript

Comment: I don't understand why we would complicate things, the div content is loaded, we can see the message on the page so it should be somewhere, accessible through the DOM!

Comment: @baptx window[0].document.getElementById("includedDiv").firstChild.nodeValue; :)

Comment: Be advised that the ability to look into the `<object>` may be subject to same-origin policy.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz sure, if you add a 2nd object element you will access his content with window[1]

Comment: that's not the point. You may find it doesn't work for `... data="http://somewhere.else.com" ...`.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Oh yes, thanks for noticing. I found this thread who explain that it is a browser security for preventing XSS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995223/error-permission-denied-to-access-property-document but isn't it possible to unlock this just for inspecting a website with Firebug?

Comment: Solution for Firebug if data is on another domain: cd command, e.g. cd(window[0]) https://groups.google.com/group/firebug/browse_thread/thread/0ef52fa0bc3e84e2/1a950b6d69b359ce https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line_API#cd.28window.29 @UlrichSchwarz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even better answer: you CAN access object tag content through the DOM, it is just another window!

```
window[0].document.getElementById("includedDiv").firstChild.nodeValue;
```

That's it :D http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_length.asp

Comment: hey, i'm trying to do the same thing but i get: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window[0].document'). Any idea?

Comment: @Miguel Sorry for the late reply, if it says window[0].document is undefined, it should mean that you don't have any frame (iframe or object) on the web page. Note that the frame should use the same domain for security reasons, otherwise you would get another error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995223/error-permission-denied-to-access-property-document

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('id').innerHTML` or `document.getElementById('id').outerHTML` whichever you are looking for...

see [how to append to a object with innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601506/how-to-append-to-a-object-with-innerhtml)

Comment: I want to get the content of an HTML page included in the "object" tag, not the content of a simple div object.

HTML object tag: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp

Comment: Unfortunately your solution works if the div is on the same page but in my case it is not and alert(document.getElementById("obj").innerHTML); prints a blank message

Comment: What about if you get the div 'includedDiv' and use outerHTML?

Comment: Also if that won't work try this... when the page loads have a function modify the window.name property to the 'innerHTML' of the loaded content and then call a callback function... When that function is called you will have the content in window.name...

Comment: document.getElementById("includedDiv").outerHTML don't work because document.getElementById("includedDiv") is null on the main page

Comment: I don't really understand your idea, have you an example?

Comment: include.onload = function () { window.name =  globalCallable(document.innerHTML.toString()); }

outerpage.globalCallable(x) { return x; }

Comment: It seems you are trying to get the content of the included page (document.body.innerHTML can work but document.innerHTML is null) and save it in the window.name property. I just discovered that the object tag is creating a new window to include the webpage, so we have 2 window.name properties, one from the main page and one from the included page, so you can't change window.name property to get this information on the other page if it's what you want to show me.

Comment: I've learned another thing about the object tag, it isn't really opening a new window to include another page, if this was the case you could easily access div content from the main page by using the method window.opener in the included page, for example window.opener.mainPagemethod(document.getElementById("includedDiv").firstChild.nodeValue). I've tried this when opening a new window with window.open() and it is working but isn't with the way object tag is opening the included page.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Just use

```
window.parent.mainPageMethod(document.getElementById("includedDiv").firstChild.nodeValue);
```

in the included page and you can get div content in a Javascript function from the main page!

Thanks for trying to help Jay, I should admit that when you talked about window.name property it put me on the right direction :)

Comment: Working, but this is still a mystery for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665108/access-external-html-page-content-of-object-tags/10753063#comment13835675_10665108